# Cassandra: How to persist and recover a thrift object?

Tags: c#, java, cassandra, thrift

Is there any way to persist a java object, thrift serialized, and recover it as a .net object, deserializing it?

I have a software, developed with java, which persist many pure objects into cassandra. Now i'd like to build a cassandra client with c# .net in order to provide the common features that exists in a simple pgadmin or mysql workbench(search,update,insert,etc) in a visual system. For this reason, it'd be necessary to deserialize the persisted objects in order to make them alterable.

Is that possible to do it by using thrift serialization?

Comment: I believe you can do this but you would have to stream the response of the Java object into a byte array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed.

I could make a BytesType column become cross language readable by persisting Thrift Serialized Objects.

At [hector issues page](https://github.com/rantav/hector/issues/379)hector issues page I posted my solution to it:

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this work for you..?
if not then disregard

```
byte[] javabuffer = new byte[1000];
using (Stream stream = myRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    stream.Read(javabuffer, 0, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Well, are you assuming that i'm persisting the java object using the simple Hector ObjectSerializer?

I need to test it. Once I do it, I answer if it has worked. Before it, i'll try to persist a thrift object using its default thrift serialization. This way, i think i can recover the thrift object directly from .net code. (thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need an interchange format, XML or JSON would be good choices. You would then persist the XML/JSON bytes against a key in Cassandra and have the code in the other language do the reverse.

HTH